# Laravel is not working with my server php version by .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, server

My server default php version is 5.6. But my laravel version is working with php 7.0

My hosting provider gives me a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

if I place this file in domain root and `phpinfo()` showing my server version is 7.0

if I remove this .htaccess file server back to my default version php 5.6

But when I make command composer update for laravel. An error message showing like:

> your php version is 5.6. laravel need php 7.0

that means laravel cannot read my .htaccess file

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run composer under php70?

Comment: I can't. When I input command php --version it shown, PHP version 5.6.32. How can I run composer under php7.0. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first you have to locate where is php7 located. Try `whereis php`

It would provide you lists of php binaries. Find one which most looks like php7 (could be like /opt/bin/7.0/bin/php)

2. Create an alias with shell command `alias php='/opt/bin/7.0/bin/php'
3. Try it
4. If it works - just add this shell command to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: I did not find any 7.0. I get these by whereis php command @server.dotnetsystem.com [~]# whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php /usr/lib/php.ini /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/li      b/php.ini,v /usr/local/lib/php /usr/local/lib/php.ini /usr/include/php /usr/loca      l/php

Comment: @SMNahidurRahman try to run each binary file and show the version. Possibly one of them still 7.0. like `/usr/bin/php -v` and `/usr/local/bin/php -v`. If this do not help, ask your hosting provider `where does php7 binaries located`

Comment: My hosting provider said,


The PHP binary exists on the system as one of the two following files:

    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php
    /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php-cgi

Comment: so try to `/usr/local/cpanel3/3dparty/bin/php -v` if it shows v7, go step 2

Comment: Now composer is okey. I input `alias php='/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/php' by putty. After if I command php --version it show PHP 7.0.25. Then I input the same command on .bashrc file. But when I command composer update in my domain, It shown same error.  - laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
What should I do?

Comment: well, alias can't help there. You have to setup path like `set PATH="/usr/local/cpanel3/3dparty/bin/:$PATH"`. It would change an order where to look up for php binary and you set to look inside mentioned folder first.